# Understanding repositories in Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a "generic" repository that query data from multiple entities. If I do that:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository {

    @Query("select r from Role r")
    List<Role> getRoles();

}
```

I get an error because Spring doesn't find an implementation to inject when a MyRepository instance is required. So far, so good. Now, If I do this:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository {

    @Query("select r from Role r")
    List<Role> getRoles();

}
```

I get an error because Object is not a JPA managed type (JpaRepository is generic). Ok, again. If I do this:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

    @Query("select r from Role r")
    List<Role> getRoles();

}
```

It works. Why? I'm declaring a JpaRepository for entity User, not Role. Why does JpaRepository need a concrete entity even when the queries will be against another one?

Comment: Because it also defines other methods like `findAll`, `findOne` etc. which will only work with, in this case, `User`. As you have specified a method with an `@Query` it looks at the method signature.

Comment: Do I have to extend JpaRepository even if I just want to do queries with @Query?

Comment: Why would you even need a query for this? Just creat a `RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long>` and use the `findAll` method. But in theory you could extend `Repository` instead of `JpaRepository` but then why do you want to use Spring Data JPA? You loose all the benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every repository in Spring Data has to extend the Repository interface, that is a generic interface, so you always have to specify the entity you are gonna work with and you can't do anything about it because it is how Spring Data is implemented. You can find more information here about creating repositories:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.0.M1/reference/html/repositories.html

On the other hand, of course you can specify one entity to the repository and then add methods that return other type of entities because in your interface you can add whatever you want (also notice that Repository interface has no methods). But if you want to use the methods of the parent interface you have to use the entity you specified.

In your example, you could do what @M. Deinum suggested and create a `JpaRepository<Role, Long>` and use the `findAll` query, that makes much more sense. Using a `JpaRepository<User, String>` as you are doing is just a misuse of the framework.

Comment: I was just trying to avoid having 30 different `{Entity}Repository`. It would be nice to have all of them in a single interface.